# MySQL query returning nothing

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I have this function in PHP:

```
function login($email, $password) {
    $email = sanitize_data($email);
    $password = sanitize_data($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `registration` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '$password'"),0) === 1) ? true : false;
}
```

I'm calling it from a conditional statement that I'm sure is OK because if I change true to false things keep going as they should. I'm pretty sure the mistake is here somewhere, I've checked my variables several times and I'm new to MySQL so I'm probably using a command wrong or something.

The function is supposed to return true if the query found at least 1 row with that combination of email and password but it returns false everytime.

This is the sanitize_data() function, even though I've already tried getting rid of it and nothing happened:

```
function sanitize_data ($data) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}
```

And the rest of the relevant code:

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($email) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and a password';
} else if (email_exists($email) === false){
    $errors[] = 'Your email is not registered';
} else {
    if(login($email, $password) === false) {
        $errors[] = "That username/password combination doesn't exist";
    }

}
```

}

HTML:

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='email' placeholder='E-Mail' class='form-email' />
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' class='form-password' />
    <input type='submit' name='sbmit' class='form-submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Lose the `COUNT()` in your query and use `mysql_num_rows`. Better yet,  don't use `mysql_*` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no issue with your `SQL Query`

look at the `SQL Query` which is executing fine as excepted see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6824f3/1)

i think strict comparison `===` might be bugging your code
try to change your code with

```
     mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `registration` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `password` = '$password'"),0) == 1
```

and also avoid using `mysql_*` it is deprecated and vulnerable to SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

1. "=== 1" is Checking for exactly one not at least one, isn't it?
2. have you tried the sql-statement f.e. in phpmyadmin or something similar?
3. have you tried to seperate your one-liner in single lines to make debugging much easier?
4. printed out the sql you generate?